# why does %superq(&bob) display variable when &bob dosn't in an %marco?

Tags: sas

i have a macro like:

```
%macro processme(uuid=);
  %put &uuid;
%mend;
```

called from another macro where uuid is generated:

```
%macro processLinks (data=);
proc sql;
reset noprint;
select uuid into :uuid1 from &data;
quit;

%local i;
%do i = 1 %to &sqlobs;

%processLink (uuid=uuid&i);

%end;
%mend;
```

and this macro is <strike>called from</strike> invoked as:

```
%processLinks(data=x.entities)
```

x.entities contains eight or so uuid in the form of 12345-123123-1234123-2342 etc

when this is run it just prints uuid1 through the uuid8 from the put command

if i change the put command to:

```
%put %superq(&uuid)
```

it then prints all uuid as expected ie 12345-123123-1234123-2342

question is why do i need to superq this to get my expected result or am i just plain doing something wrong ( again :) )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In procesLink macro variable uuid contains uuid1 and not actually the uuid itself than uuid1 is given to superq which than resolvs to the actual uuid. You could also use &&& instead of superq

example

```
%macro m(b);
  %put &b;
  %put %superq(&b);
  %put &&&b;
%mend;
%let a=5;
%m(b=a)
```

output

```
a
5
5
```

but more correct would be to `call %m(b=&a)`